# Retornar o índice de uma linha com a função min em Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Estou tentando encontrar o índice de uma matriz numpy (recorte de uma face detectada em opencv) e desenhar uma linha aonde a soma dos pixel for o valor mínimo.

Não consigo retornar o índice.

Segue abaixo o código

```
for (x, y, l, a) in facesDetectadas:
    # Recortar a região do rosto redimensionada em 200 x 200        
    rosto = cv2.resize(frame[y:y + a, x:x + l], (200, 200))             

    # Desenhar um retangulo na região do rosto      
    cv2.rectangle( frame, (x,y) , (x+l, y+a) , (0,0,255) , 2)

    rosto = rosto.astype(np.uint16)
    b,g,r = cv2.split(rosto)
    olhos = (b + g + r)

    linhaOlhos = np.sum(olhos, axis = 0)
    marcarOlhos = linhaOlhos.min(axis = 0)

    cv2.rectangle(rosto, (0,marcarOlhos) , (199,marcarOlhos), (0,0,255) , 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

O `for` em Python é sempre um `for each`: ou seja, ele sempre vai percorrer os elementos de uma sequência, no caso a sua `facesDetectadas`, e não, como é necessário na maior parte das outras linguagens, um `for` que vai fazer uma variável de índice assumir um valor de 0 até o comprimento da sequência, para dentro do `for` ter-se que obter o elemento da sequência (por ex. com `x, y, l, a = facesDetectadas[i]`).

Eventualmente, além dos elementos em si, precisamos também dos índices dos elementos. Nesses casos, pode-se usar a função builtin `enumerate` - que, para cada elemento de uma sequência, retorna uma tupla com o índice do elemento e o elemento em si.

Então, é possível fazer:

```
valor_min, index_min = None, -1

for index, (x, y, a, l) in  enumerate(facesDetectadas):
    ...
    linhaOlhos = np.sum(olhos, axis = 0)
    if valor_min is None or valor_min > linhaOlhos:
         index_min = index
         valor_min = linhaOlhos
    ...
```

Pronto - ao final do `for`,  `index_min` contém o índice de facesDetectadas para o qual esse valor é mínimo.

Deixo também uma dica de estilo: evite usar o nome `l` para uma variável - mesmo em casos diretos como esse, em que ela é sempre usada em conjunto com `x, y, l , a`, e portanto trata-se de "largura", essa letra sozinha parece muito com o dígito `1`, e, olhando o programa uma pessoa tem que ficar um tempo pensado se está vendo um `x + 1` ou um `x + l`.  Se for usar variáveis em português, use uma abreviação menor - `larg` mesmo, ou use as letras em inglês para esse caso.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizando a funcao `np.argmin` seguinte forma:

```
import numpy as np
for (x, y, l, a) in facesDetectadas:
    # Recortar a região do rosto redimensionada em 200 x 200        
    rosto = cv2.resize(frame[y:y + a, x:x + l], (200, 200))             

    # Desenhar um retangulo na região do rosto      
    cv2.rectangle( frame, (x,y) , (x+l, y+a) , (0,0,255) , 2)

    rosto = rosto.astype(np.uint16)
    b,g,r = cv2.split(rosto)
    olhos = (b + g + r)

    linhaOlhos = np.sum(olhos, axis = 0)
    marcarOlhos = np.argmin(linhaOlhos)

    cv2.rectangle(rosto, (0,marcarOlhos) , (199,marcarOlhos), (0,0,255) , 2)
```